# How to clone/inherit from a job using Jenkins Job DSL?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

So I have a lot of Jenkins jobs defined using the DSL in groovy files like this:

```
def param1 = "foo"
def param2 = "bar"
job(jobName) {
 // stuff
}
```

I need to find a way to automatically create new clones of these jobs, but with the values of the params changed (for a second test pipeline). Is there a way to do this using inheritance, or using a custom Seed DSL script? I haven't found anything yet. The important thing is that when the base job is updated, the cloned job receives the same change.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Jenkins pipeline and inheritance are not very good friends. You can use the jenkins shared library to create a template build definition in /vars/mytemplate.groovy and pass from the jenkins file only the parameters needed for execution. That would give you something similar with an interface . Further more, you can define classes in src folder and use them in the template. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: I have the same use case. I've tried implementing something based on this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Real-World-Examples#import-other-files-ie-with-class-definitions-into-your-script but have not been able to get it to work yet.